# Eclipse Plugin executes Javafx application

Tags: eclipse, plugins, javafx, eclipse-kepler

here's my problem:
I'm developing an Eclipse Plugin which should start an Javafx-application. Should be pretty easy actually, but i still got an issue.
Here my Code-example for the simple fx-app:

```
public class UIContainer extends Application{



public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("First FXML Example");
    Pane myPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui.fxml"));
    Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Now i want to run the application from an Eclipse Plugin Handler like this:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

   IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
   //Call the UIContainer here
   //do sth. else
   return null;
}
```

There is actually no difference in calling the application via the main or the start-method according to the error-message.

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application cannot be found by XODR-Validator_0.0.1.qualifier
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 60 more
```

Hopefully you can track my problem in order to find the solution.

My Configuration:
Eclipse Kepler (IDE for EE Developer)
JDK1.7.0_40

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Should this app get launched as an extra process?
2. If you are launching from with in Eclipse the classpath in which you are executing the class is the one from the current bundle which most likely has no idea what you are doing (unless you are using e(fx)clipse and its adapter hooks) and even if it would you are most likely getting into trouble because FX and SWT share the same event loop and but don't know from each other the way you have written it, to embed FX into SWT you should use FXCanvas.

Comment: It should get launched after pressing a menu item.
Based on the fact that an Eclipse-Plugin is a SWT by default, I should get in touch with FXCanvas, right?
Thanks, im gonna try that one.

Comment: well if it is simply a dialog then yes - you'd better implement it as an JFace-Dialog or an SWT-Shell holding the FX-Content in an FXCanvas but I'm not sure what your use case is.

Anyways you'll have to use e(fx)clipse when you are in OSGi without you won't be able to locate the javafx-libs who are NOT on the classpath in Java7, repackaging FX in your product is doommed to fail either (see http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/08/01/javafx-2-2-and-osgi/)

Comment: FX is not mandatory but would be great to use. Anyway I'm gonna try to wrap it into an SWT-Shell.